# Export 2013 User Profiles from UPSA -Multi Value - Managed MetaData

Tags: 2013, powershell, user-profile-service, user-profile-property, sharepoint-administration

I am using the following script from GitHub to export user profile properties from SharePoint 2013 into a .csv file.

Unfortunately, I'm only getting the first value for properties where multiple managed metadata/term set values have been selected. Does anyone know of a way to get all the values for the property?

In the script below for example, Groups would have multiple values.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Script    : To Export User Profile Information Value in Excel
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$siteUrl = "<Central Admin URL>"
$outputFile = "D:\SP2016\SP2016_UPS_AllUserProfiles.csv"
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext -Site $siteUrl
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext);
$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()
$collection = @()
foreach ($profile in $profiles) {
 
   $profileData = "" | 
   select "AccountName", "PreferredName" , "Groups" , "LDAP" , "Office" , "Location" , "WorkEmail" , "HireDate", "Manager"
   
   $profileData.AccountName = $profile["AccountName"]
   $profileData.PreferredName = $profile["PreferredName"]
   $profileData.WorkEmail = $profile["WorkEmail"]
   $profileData.Office = $profile["Office"]
   $profileData.Groups = $profile["Groups"]
   $profileData.HireDate = $profile["SPS-HireDate"]
   $profileData.Location = $profile["Location"]
   $profileData.LDAP = $profile["SPS-DistinguishedName"]
   
   $collection += $profileData
}
$collection | Export-Csv $outputFile -NoTypeInformation
```